# How to calculate a variance of "2-stage" bernoulli trials?

Tags: variance, bernoulli-distribution

Let's say I am running a survey, where I want respondents to answer a yes/no question.

With probability `t` the respondents answer truthfully. If they answer truthfully, they answer "yes" with probability `p1`. If they decide to lie, they answer "yes" with probability `p2`.

I would like to know the variance of the process describing the likelihood that a person answers yes?

My understanding is, that if `T~bernoulli(t)`, `X~bernoulli(p1)`, `Y~bernoulli(p2)`,

Then I am looking for `Var(T*X + (1-T)*Y)`? Is that right? If yes, how can I express the variance in terms of `t`, `p1`, `p2`?

Moreover, if I had a ratio of two such variables, what would be the variance then?

Note: This is not a self-study question, though I understand it might sound a bit textbookish.

Comment: You might look at the probability that they answer "yes", which seems to be $tp_1+(1-t)p_2$.  You might also wonder whether each respondent acts independently of the others

Comment: They act independently of each other. Also, you are right about the probability with which they answer yes. 

Would then the variance be just (tp1 + (1-t)p2) * (1 -  (tp1 + (1-t)p2))? I guess, it should be right? Why I didn't think of this before writing the whole question...